# Using the definition of convergence , show that $a_n=\sqrt{n+1}- \sqrt{n}$ Converges to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definition

How do I apply this finding to the definition:

So far I have got that:

\begin{align}
a_n &=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \\
&=\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt n} \right)\\
&=\frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt n} \\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt n} 
\end{align}

Comment: You are almost there. What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}$?

Comment: Now let $n \to \infty$ and you're done.

Comment: Well, $$0<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ then use Squeeze Theorem

Answer (score 5):

Since $$\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n} \geq \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n},$$

we have

$$0 \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}=0$$

Comment: I don't  understand the steps you have taken to come to this conclusion.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: How do I know 1/2sqrt(n) is equal to 0, as n approaches infinity.

Comment: Do you know that $\frac1{n}$ converges to $0$? Notice that square root function is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

$|a_n|=\left|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\right|\lt$

$\left|\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt n}\right|.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

There is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such  that

$n_0 > \dfrac{1}{4\epsilon^2}$, i.e. $\epsilon > \dfrac {1}{2\sqrt{n_0}}$(Archimedes).

Then for $n\ge n_0 :$

$|a_n| \lt \dfrac {1}{2\sqrt n} \le \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n_0}} \lt \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for editing, Thomas.